# android SqLite AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, autocompletetextview

I want to create a table that has the columns `EMPLOYER NAME`, `DATE`, `QUANTITY`, and `HOURS`. Once the table is saved for employer name, next, time the `AutoCompleteTextView` for name should show the already saved employers name.

Comment: do you want to code or procedure?

Comment: code... please send me it is urgent.

Comment: you should try this at your own, If any problem and Errors then inform us. Its not for providing code.

Answer (score 1):

1. create a table in sqlite database.
2. after it fetch the records from it using select query.
3. and pass these records to auto complete text view as a string[].

Comment: Important: Make sure you're performing these actions in the background.  Database access can lock up the UI.  You also need to make sure you insert these records at some point.